# Service Call on Page Generates Zone Security Error

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, rest, webmethod

This error is received on an ajax call

> WebSocket Error: SECURITY_ERR, Cross zone connection not allowed

<strike>with a 500 error code also returned</strike>. *I am able to get other responses which don't seem to be related to the error upon further testing. See below for where the reported error is.*

From this Angular call

```
$http.post("Status.aspx/GetDataAsync", {})
     .then(function(response){ $scope.theData = data;},
           function(response){ $scope.result  = "Error!";}
     );
```

when attempting to call a page's code behind `WebMethod` which tellingly **also makes a webservice call** to a rest web service.

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static async Task<string> GetDataAsync()
{ 
   var httpresult = await (new HttpClient()).GetAsync("{Internal site rest service Url}");
   return await httpresult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

This reminds me of an old Silverlight cross-domain issue call...but I digress.

**Question**
Can the zone issue be resolved or does one have to call rest services directly?

---

**Attempt** The use of CORS (see [Enabling Cross-Origin Requests (CORS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors#set-the-allowed-http-methods))  at the method level such as

```
 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
 [EnableCors("AllowAllOrigins", "AllowHeaders", "AllowAllMethods")]
```

to no luck.

---

**Error**

[image: F12 Tools Error]

This is where the error is found, in the F12 tools on Edge (and IE). **Chrome does not report the issue.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set the Content Security Policy (CSP) of your page so that your {Internal site rest service Url} is not blocked by the browser.

Here are links, combined, that helped me solve this issue:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/connect-src
http://caniuse.com/#feat=contentsecuritypolicy

For MVC, I placed the following in the web.config:

> ```
>     <httpProtocol>
>       <customHeaders>
>         <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="connect-src 'self' wss://localhost:7717" />
>       </customHeaders>
>     </httpProtocol>
> ```

I was then able to create a websocket connection to wss://localhost:7717, but wasn't able to connect to any other port.

Browsers block these kinds of requests to prevent cross-zone script attacks, so you need your page to set the policy, done through the http header. I'm working on a similar issue. I'm missing something, but I think this is the right direction. I need others input because this isn't quite solving the issue. It's closer, though.